Ubuntu 22.04 - Mysql crash
I set up a new VPS 10 days ago (Ubuntu 22.04 / 2 CPU / 2 GB RAM), everything was running fine until last night : I found out in the syslog that MySQL had crashed. Here is what I have the logs before the mysql process was killed at 3:25 (with an "out of memory" message). I'm just running a PHP/MySQL website, nothing extraordinary. I saw the VPS has no SWAP but it seems normal on Ubuntu 22.04... Any other idea ? Thanks a lot
Jul  6 03:17:01 ubuntu CRON[636759]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.692963] snumbdctl_open(mms,144984): OK
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.693486] session_init(mms,144984): OK. kdev=fb:1, len=8192 sect=512 s=00000000fd3cdcdb pgrp=(144881).
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.698267] snumbd_release_blk(mms,144984): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=104
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.701626] snumbd_open_blk(systemd-udevd,636865): Disable access (399,144881,144881)...
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.705834] snumbd_open_blk(probe-bcache,636867): Disable access (399,144881,144881)...
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu systemd-udevd[636865]: snumbd1d: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/snumbd1d' failed with exit code 1.
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.790694] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=336
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.791741] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=338
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.792006] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=340
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.799211] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=342
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.799452] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=344
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.799658] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=345
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.799741] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=345
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.799946] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636866): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=353
Jul  6 03:18:34 ubuntu kernel: [907782.813769] snumbdctl_release(mms,144984): OK. kdev=0:0
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.910849] snumbdctl_open(mms,144984): OK
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.912777] session_init(mms,144984): OK. kdev=fb:1, len=8192 sect=512 s=00000000f04a2e33 pgrp=(144881).
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.913193] snumbd_open_blk(systemd-udevd,636864): Disable access (399,144881,144881)...
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.916415] snumbd_open_blk(probe-bcache,636877): Disable access (399,144881,144881)...
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.917459] snumbd_release_blk(mms,144984): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=104
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu systemd-udevd[636864]: snumbd1d: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/snumbd1d' failed with exit code 1.
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.992595] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=336
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907782.997370] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=338
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.005792] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=340
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.008006] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=342
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.008371] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=344
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.012452] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=345
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.012585] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=345
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.012924] snumbd_release_blk(mount,636879): dev=fb00001, IO (sectors) write=0 read=353
Jul  6 03:18:35 ubuntu kernel: [907783.071650] snumbdctl_release(mms,144984): OK. kdev=0:0
Jul  6 03:19:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jul  6 03:19:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Update APT News...
Jul  6 03:19:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Update the local ESM caches...
Jul  6 03:19:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  6 03:19:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jul  6 03:19:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  6 03:19:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402374] snapapi_prht: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0xc2(__GFP_HIGHMEM|__GFP_IO|__GFP_FS), nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402387] CPU: 0 PID: 633742 Comm: snapapi_prht Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-112-generic #122-Ubuntu
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402391] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.14.0-2 04/01/2014
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402393] Call Trace:
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402395]  <TASK>
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402399]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402405]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402409]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402411]  warn_alloc+0x138/0x160
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402419]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xa44/0xa80
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402423]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402428]  __alloc_pages+0x311/0x330
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402433]  alloc_pages+0x9e/0x1e0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402439]  sa_cache_save+0x425/0x550 [snapapi26]
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402446]  pending_req_handler_thread+0x1cb/0x390 [snapapi26]
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402450]  ? snapapi_ops_submit_bio+0x230/0x230 [snapapi26]
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402454]  kthread+0x12a/0x150
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402458]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402461]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402468]  </TASK>
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402469] Mem-Info:
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471] active_anon:4534 inactive_anon:352929 isolated_anon:0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  active_file:8297 inactive_file:13392 isolated_file:13
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  unevictable:6919 dirty:773 writeback:0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  slab_reclaimable:10252 slab_unreclaimable:17702
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  mapped:20141 shmem:4608 pagetables:3044 bounce:0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402471]  free:20682 free_pcp:351 free_cma:0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402476] Node 0 active_anon:18136kB inactive_anon:1411716kB active_file:33188kB inactive_file:53736kB unevictable:27676kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):52kB mapped:80564kB dirty:3092kB writeback:0kB shmem:18432kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:11416kB pagetables:12176kB all_unreclaimable? no
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402481] Node 0 DMA free:9604kB min:368kB low:460kB high:552kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:4548kB active_file:68kB inactive_file:236kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15360kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402487] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1808 1808 1808 1808
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402493] Node 0 DMA32 free:73124kB min:52876kB low:64044kB high:75212kB reserved_highatomic:20480KB active_anon:18136kB inactive_anon:1407420kB active_file:32760kB inactive_file:53732kB unevictable:27676kB writepending:2924kB present:2080620kB managed:1892316kB mlocked:27676kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1404kB local_pcp:608kB free_cma:0kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402500] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402505] Node 0 DMA: 44*4kB (MEH) 21*8kB (MEH) 16*16kB (UMEH) 12*32kB (UEH) 5*64kB (UMEH) 11*128kB (UMEH) 5*256kB (UME) 3*512kB (M) 2*1024kB (UE) 1*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB = 9624kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402528] Node 0 DMA32: 4332*4kB (UMEH) 1176*8kB (UMEH) 574*16kB (UMEH) 329*32kB (UMEH) 179*64kB (UMEH) 69*128kB (UMEH) 16*256kB (UMH) 3*512kB (UH) 1*1024kB (U) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 73392kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402550] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402553] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402554] 28610 total pagecache pages
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402555] 0 pages in swap cache
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402557] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402558] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402559] Total swap = 0kB
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402561] 524153 pages RAM
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402562] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402563] 47234 pages reserved
Jul  6 03:19:34 ubuntu kernel: [907842.402563] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jul  6 03:24:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 5min)!
Jul  6 03:24:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 657 (snapd) with signal SIGABRT.
Jul  6 03:25:15 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575957] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575965] CPU: 1 PID: 635988 Comm: apache2 Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-112-generic #122-Ubuntu
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575969] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.14.0-2 04/01/2014
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575971] Call Trace:
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575973]  <TASK>
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575976]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575982]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575987]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575989]  dump_header+0x53/0x228
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575993]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.575996]  out_of_memory+0x106/0x2e0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576001]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x9b7/0xa80
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576008]  __alloc_pages+0x311/0x330
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576012]  alloc_pages+0x9e/0x1e0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576017]  __page_cache_alloc+0x7e/0x90
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576020]  pagecache_get_page+0x152/0x590
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576023]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576026]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x163/0x210
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576031]  filemap_fault+0x488/0xab0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576033]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576036]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x309/0x400
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576039]  __do_fault+0x3c/0x120
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576043]  do_read_fault+0xeb/0x160
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576045]  do_fault+0xa0/0x2e0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576048]  handle_pte_fault+0x1cd/0x240
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576051]  __handle_mm_fault+0x405/0x6f0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576056]  handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576059]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1c9/0x670
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576064]  exc_page_fault+0x77/0x170
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576068]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576071] RIP: 0033:0x7fd9c75cbf50
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576080] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fd9c75cbf26.
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576081] RSP: 002b:00007ffeb43a1e58 EFLAGS: 00010246
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576084] RAX: 00007fd9c7643140 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576086] RDX: 000000000000001e RSI: 000000000000004c RDI: 000055bbe20e44a0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576088] RBP: 0000000000000200 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007fd9c4f75290
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576089] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000200
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576091] R13: 0000000000000200 R14: 000055bbe1df7b00 R15: 00007ffeb43a1f38
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576095]  </TASK>
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576096] Mem-Info:
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098] active_anon:4539 inactive_anon:373466 isolated_anon:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  active_file:2 inactive_file:246 isolated_file:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  unevictable:6919 dirty:0 writeback:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  slab_reclaimable:10176 slab_unreclaimable:18316
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  mapped:6237 shmem:4608 pagetables:3434 bounce:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576098]  free:14080 free_pcp:287 free_cma:0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576104] Node 0 active_anon:18156kB inactive_anon:1493864kB active_file:8kB inactive_file:984kB unevictable:27676kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:24948kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:18432kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:11504kB pagetables:13736kB all_unreclaimable? no
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576109] Node 0 DMA free:9636kB min:368kB low:460kB high:552kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:4616kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:44kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15360kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:44kB local_pcp:44kB free_cma:0kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576116] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1808 1808 1808 1808
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576122] Node 0 DMA32 free:46684kB min:44684kB low:55852kB high:67020kB reserved_highatomic:4096KB active_anon:18156kB inactive_anon:1489248kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:956kB unevictable:27676kB writepending:0kB present:2080620kB managed:1892316kB mlocked:27676kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1104kB local_pcp:796kB free_cma:0kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576127] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576133] Node 0 DMA: 75*4kB (UMEH) 33*8kB (UMEH) 15*16kB (MEH) 12*32kB (UEH) 4*64kB (MEH) 10*128kB (UMEH) 5*256kB (UME) 3*512kB (M) 2*1024kB (UE) 1*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB = 9636kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576156] Node 0 DMA32: 2600*4kB (UMEH) 1218*8kB (MEH) 539*16kB (UMEH) 201*32kB (UMEH) 114*64kB (MEH) 29*128kB (MH) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 46208kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576176] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576178] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576180] 7175 total pagecache pages
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576181] 0 pages in swap cache
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576182] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576184] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576185] Total swap = 0kB
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576186] 524153 pages RAM
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576187] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576188] 47234 pages reserved
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576189] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576190] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576191] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576194] [    364]     0   364    49817      788   421888        0          -250 systemd-journal
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576199] [    398]     0   398    72329     6775   114688        0         -1000 multipathd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576202] [    399]     0   399     5795      929    73728        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576205] [    484]   103   484    22341      726    65536        0             0 systemd-timesyn
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576208] [    625]   100   625     4032      633    69632        0             0 systemd-network
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576211] [    627]   101   627     6418     1624    94208        0             0 systemd-resolve
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576214] [    639]     0   639     1822      566    57344        0             0 cron
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576216] [    642]   102   642     2206      846    53248        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576219] [    651]     0   651    20675      780    57344        0             0 irqbalance
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576222] [    653]     0   653     8244     2814   102400        0             0 networkd-dispat
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576225] [    654]   104   654    55601      979    77824        0             0 rsyslogd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576228] [    657]     0   657   330081     2972   266240        0          -900 snapd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576230] [    659]     0   659     3871      871    65536        0             0 systemd-logind
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576233] [    683]     0   683     1555      219    49152        0             0 agetty
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576235] [    717]     0   717    27528     2832   110592        0             0 unattended-upgr
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576238] [    718]     0   718    56827     3424   184320        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576241] [    721]   113   721   481415   191666  2199552        0             0 mysqld
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576244] [    993]     0   993     1918      676    53248        0             0 login
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576246] [   1070]     0  1070     4274      656    73728        0             0 systemd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576249] [   1071]     0  1071    42321      947    90112        0             0 (sd-pam)
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576252] [   1077]     0  1077     2271      907    53248        0             0 bash
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576255] [   8431]     0  8431    73998     1253   167936        0             0 packagekitd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576258] [   8435]     0  8435    58626      217    86016        0             0 polkitd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576260] [  90536]     0 90536     2075      717    61440        0             0 dbus-daemon
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576263] [ 144696]     0 144696   435364     5658   303104        0             0 aakore
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576266] [ 144704]     0 144704   181274      817   176128        0             0 grpm-sync-unit
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576269] [ 144705]     0 144705   212866     1085   212992        0             0 updater
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576272] [ 144706]     0 144706   179043     1085   118784        0             0 feedback-collec
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576275] [ 144707]     0 144707   264904     2172   176128        0             0 cred-store
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576277] [ 144708]     0 144708   370823     5558   282624        0             0 task-manager
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576280] [ 144709]     0 144709   284039     1852   397312        0             0 adp-agent
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576283] [ 144847]     0 144847   260281      447   208896        0             0 schedul2-bin
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576287] [ 144881]     0 144881   159921    27861  1286144        0             0 mms
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576290] [ 144934]     0 144934   430439    30115   741376        0             0 active-protecti
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576297] [ 145001]     0 145001   249613      716   258048        0             0 acp-update-cont
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576302] [ 404206]     0 404206     3859      926    73728        0         -1000 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576307] [ 629610]     0 629610   126032      455   176128        0             0 cyber-desktop-s
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576311] [ 633453]     0 633453    57120      691   110592        0             0 act-bin
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576315] [ 633517]     0 633517   135912    54041  1101824        0             0 service_process
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576319] [ 633931]    33 633931    57169     6673   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576322] [ 634105]    33 634105    57147     6838   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576325] [ 634294]    33 634294    57159     6562   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576328] [ 635726]    33 635726    57096     6648   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576330] [ 635727]    33 635727    57129     6759   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576333] [ 635728]    33 635728    57114     6738   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576336] [ 635988]    33 635988    57102     6779   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576338] [ 635989]    33 635989    57106     6322   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576341] [ 636432]    33 636432    57097     6593   225280        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576344] [ 636457]    33 636457    57095     6456   221184        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576346] [ 636939]     0 636939      723      209    45056        0             0 apt.systemd.dai
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576350] [ 636943]     0 636943      723      430    45056        0             0 apt.systemd.dai
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576352] [ 636973]     0 636973     4662     1780    81920        0             0 apt-get
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576355] [ 637263]     0 637263     4662     1073    77824        0             0 apt-get
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576358] [ 637277]     0 637277      723      222    45056        0             0 sh
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576361] [ 637278]     0 637278      723      445    49152        0             0 update-motd-upd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576363] [ 637292]     0 637292    32020    20261   249856        0             0 apt-check
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576366] [ 637308]    33 637308    56912     2547   163840        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576369] [ 637309]    33 637309    56912     2487   167936        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576371] [ 637311]    33 637311    56908     2426   159744        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576374] [ 637312]    33 637312    56912     2530   163840        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576377] [ 637313]    33 637313    56908     2531   159744        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576379] [ 637314]    33 637314    56912     2441   163840        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576382] [ 637315]     0 637315    56914     2462   159744        0             0 apache2
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576385] [ 637316]     0 637316     3859      941    73728        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576387] [ 637318]     0 637318     3722      709    69632        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576390] [ 637321]     0 637321     3657      422    65536        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576392] [ 637322]     0 637322     3657      305    61440        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576395] [ 637323]     0 637323     3657      282    61440        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576398] [ 637325]     0 637325     3615      212    57344        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576400] [ 637326]     0 637326     2758      106    53248        0             0 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576403] [ 637329]     0 637329     3859      407    69632        0         -1000 sshd
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576406] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=apache2.service,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysql.service,task=mysqld,pid=721,uid=113
Jul  6 03:25:17 ubuntu kernel: [908183.576467] Out of memory: Killed process 721 (mysqld) total-vm:1925660kB, anon-rss:766664kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:113 pgtables:2148kB oom_score_adj:0
Jul  6 03:25:18 ubuntu kernel: [908185.882994] oom_reaper: reaped process 721 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

If I run the command free right now, I get :
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         1907696     1077736       93312       23588      736648      635512
Swap:              0           0           0


2GB seems low for today's standards, even on Linux, unless maybe we're talking about Ubuntu server which has a smaller footprint but still, I would swap to a swapfile at least 4GB in size just to be safe. And I'd update MySQL to the latest version, to rule out MySQL itself possibly leaking. Other than that, the issue might be app-dependent, or it could be due to many clients connecting at the same time, spawning multiple threads and leading to an increased memory consumption. Regardless, for starters I would try to update MySQL to the latest version and start using swap
